# Microsoft SSRS Chart - vary background color between gridlines of chart

Tags: reporting-services, charts, ssrs-2012, gridlines, report-designer

I have a situation like this, in which I am developing a simple chart.

I need the background color of the chart to vary between the gridlines.

See sample image below (I want this to be developed in SSRS):

[image]

Is there a way, I can get white and gray colors to alternate between the gridlines ?

Please let me know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out; in the **Y - axis properties**, Vertical Axis Properties,in the **Scale options**, check the box - **'Use Interlacing color'**

Then I can either use the automatic color in this choice, or vary the color in this choice with the background color of the report.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

There is no built-in support for alternating background colors like what you described. However, you do have the option of using a background image. It might take some work to get the alignment right, but you could create that as an image and use that in the chart.

Sorry it's probably not the answer you were hoping for, but at least it's a workaround if you don't have any other options.